PMD Cyclomatic Complexity Causing Problem - Can I Disable?
I'm running a Gradle (Kotlin) build in Java, and overall it's going well. However, the PMD report is set to automatically stop the build if the cyclomatic complexity is 5 or more. This hasn't been too much of a problem, except that I'm using a Hoare partition quick sort, and I can't get the cyclomatic complexity below 5 without making the code too complicated.
private int hoarePartition(int low, int high) {
    selectAndPlaceMedianOfThreeAsPivot(low, high);
    int i = low - 1, j = high + 1;
    int pivotvalue = keyCharacterList.get(low);
    while (true) {
      do {
        i++;
      } while (keyCharacterList.get(i) < pivotvalue);

      do {
        j--;
      } while (keyCharacterList.get(j) > pivotvalue);

      if (i >= j)
        return j;

      Collections.swap(keyCharacterList, i, j);
    }
  }

Is there a way to modify the build so that it either raises the cyclomatic complexity threshold or so it gives me a warning instead of just stopping the build entirely?
I've tried looking for different solutions, but so far I really haven't found much in the way of solving this particular problem.

Absolutely!
There are two ways around this problem:

Simply suppress this particular instance of this report. The rule will still apply everywhere else, but will ignore this method. You can do so both with a NOPMD comment or with a @SuppressWarning("PMD.xxx") annotation. The docs for suppression are available here

You can create your own ruleset, and either not include this rule, or change it's configuration. Creating your own ruleset is actually the recommended way to use PMD, but will require some time to review all available rules to pick from and configure them. Finally, you can configure Gradle to use this custom ruleset instead of whatever Gradle decides to apply by default.



Thanks so much! I'll probably use the first in this instance just so I can make sure the rest of the build is working, but I'll definitely look into the second option for when I'm moving forward!
